# Ajax devuelve error pero funciona correctamente

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo este código que guarda ciertos valores en la base de datos. El tema es que, el botón `guardar` se comporta correctamente, los datos quedan bien guardados, pero la respuesta de `Ajax` sale desde el `error` y no desde el `success`. Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

> Llamada Ajax

```
    var data = {};
    data.idCliente = idCliente;
    data.fecha = fechaRemito;
    data.datos = datosRemito;


    // Aca tengo que llamar a ajax y mandar datos, cargarlo en la base y sacar un success de alerta suave

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/remitos.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,

        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {

            alert("Funcionó")
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error")
        }
    })
```

> remitos.ajax.php

```
<?php

require_once "../modelos/conexion.php";


if (isset($_POST['idCliente']) && !empty($_POST['idCliente']) && isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha']) && isset($_POST['datos']) && !empty($_POST['datos'])) {


    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $datos = $_POST["datos"];
    $tabla = "remitos";

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(id_cliente, fecha, datos) VALUES ( :id_cliente , :fecha, :datos)");   

    $stmt->bindParam(":id_cliente", $idCliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":datos", $datos, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt -> execute();

    return "ok";



    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;


}
```

Comment: Si intentas validar si esto retorna true $stmt -> execute();
Ademas puedes probar haciendo echo ok, o true en vez de return

Comment: Si devuelves **return true** tienes el mismo comportamiento?

Comment: Si @Bicho, el mismo comportamiento probando todas las variantes mencionadas

Comment: Si imprimes el parámetro error qué te devuelve?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta sustituir el `return` por un `echo`, ademas en tu código no continua con la instrucción  `close()` ya que haces el `return` antes.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
require_once "../modelos/conexion.php";
$resp=array('success' => 0,'message'=>'error, faltan datos');
if (isset($_POST['idCliente']) && !empty($_POST['idCliente']) && isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha']) && isset($_POST['datos']) && !empty($_POST['datos'])) {

    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $datos = $_POST["datos"];
    $tabla = "remitos";

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(id_cliente, fecha, datos) VALUES ( :id_cliente , :fecha, :datos)");   

    $stmt->bindParam(":id_cliente", $idCliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":datos", $datos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
    $resp["success"]=1;
    $resp["message"]="operacón correcta";

    //echo "success";        
}
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: la ultima linea me devuelve unos cuantos erroes, y quitandola no hace nada, sigue comportandose igual

Comment: faltaba => en message actualizarlo y prueba

Comment: No, sigue saliendo del lado del error.

Comment: en ajax sustituye  method: "POST", por  type: "POST",

Comment: nop, tampoco. ahora no vuelvo a mi casa hasta la noche, donde voy a poder seguir haciendo pruebas tranquilo. Gracias por el tiempo, si encuentro la solucion antes la comento aca para que edites la respuesta.